# Google sheets: conditional formatting of a row based on today() and date cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to do conditional formatting using Google Sheets:

I have a table with a date on the left side, where every row marks a different day.
Wanted outcome: mark the row that is today in bold with conditional formatting so this happens automatic.

Example made in Excel: [link to sheet](https://ufile.io/g99jwlem)

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup Google Sheets conditional formatting to highlight/bold the entire row by following the steps below:

1.) On the conditional formatting window, set the range that the highlighting will apply.

2.) Under Format rules.. use `Custom formula is` and `=$A2=TODAY()` as the formula value.

3.) Select your preferred formatting style.

Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jason, it worked.